# Fail fast with MPI4PY

Tags: openmpi, mpi4py

I'd like the following behavior when running an MPI script with mpi4py: when any process throws an exception, mpirun (and its spawned processes) should immediately exit with non-zero error codes. But instead, I find that execution continues even if one or more processes throws an exception.

I am using mpi4py 3.0.0 with OpenMPI 2.1.2. I'm running this script with
`mpirun --verbose -mca orte_abort_on_non_zero_status 1 -n 4 python my_script.py`. I expected this to immediately end before the sleep is hit, but instead, processes with ranks != 0 sleep:

```
import time
import mpi4py

def main():
    import mpi4py.MPI
    mpi_comm = mpi4py.MPI.COMM_WORLD
    if mpi_comm.rank == 0:
        raise ValueError('Failure')


    print('{} continuing to execute'.format(mpi_comm.rank))
    time.sleep(10)
    print('{} exiting'.format(mpi_comm.rank)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I get the behavior I'd like (fail quickly if any process fails)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be an known issue of mpi4py. From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mpi4py/RovYzJ8qkbc, I read:

> mpi4py initializes/finalizes MPI for you. The initialization occurs at
>   import time, and the finalization when the Python process is about to
>   finalize (I'm using Py_AtExit() C-API call to do this). As
>   MPI_Finalize() is collective and likely blocking in most MPI impls,
>   you get the deadlock.

A solution is to override  `sys.excepthook`and call explicitly `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Abort` in it.

Here is your code modified:

```
import sys
import time
import mpi4py.MPI
mpi_comm = mpi4py.MPI.COMM_WORLD

def mpiabort_excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    mpi_comm.Abort()
    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, traceback)

def main():
    if mpi_comm.rank == 0:
        raise ValueError('Failure')


    print('{} continuing to execute'.format(mpi_comm.rank))
    time.sleep(10)
    print('{} exiting'.format(mpi_comm.rank))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.excepthook = mpiabort_excepthook
    main()
    sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
```

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks -- I just updated this with an answer I got from the mpi4py bitbucket repo.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out mpi4py can be run as a module fixing this issue (internally by calling Abort() like jcgiret says):

```
mpirun --verbose -mca orte_abort_on_non_zero_status 1 -n 4 python -m mpi4py my_script.py
```

Comment: Note this only works if `mpi4py` is built on top of Open MPI, and does not work if you use direct launch (e.g. `srun` under `SLURM`) @jcgiret solution is portable and hence a better option imho.